# How to use String Icon name in inside the icons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, icons, material-design, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

How to use String name in Icon data.
Flutter doesn't allow to make changes in Icons only allows Material Design Icons only
I tried several ways like data[index] but it didn't work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: GetxLearn()));
}

class GetxLearn extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _GetxLearnState createState() => _GetxLearnState();
}

class _GetxLearnState extends State<GetxLearn> {
  List<String> data = [
    "add",
    "assistant_direction",
    "tablet",
    "new_label",
    "add",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Center(
                child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.new_label,
                //Icons.data[index] ====> need this type
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ));
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is that you can generate images to font icon (Generate to font). save ttf file in assets. pass unicode data to json (like "e90a").

```
Icon(IconData(int.parse('0x${e90a}',
    fontFamily: 'family name given in the link above'));
```

Comment: I want to use  this list icons                                                                                                      List<String> data = [
    "add",
    "assistant_direction",
    "tablet",
    "new_label",
    "add",
  ];

Answer (score 1):

`Icons.add` is defined as

```dart
static const IconData add = IconData(0xe047, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

`add` is a static variable inside `Icons`.

You can create a list of int that will hold codePoint of Icon.

```dart
 List<int> data = [
    0xe047,
    Icons.face.codePoint,
    ....
  ];
```

And use like

```dart
 IconData(data[index], fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
```

You can get IconCode from [flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) or you can use like `Icons.face.codePoint,`

Comment: I want to use  this list icons                                                                                                      List<String> data = [
    "add",
    "assistant_direction",
    "tablet",
    "new_label",
    "add",
  ];

Comment: I am afraid It might not be possible while there are nth icons. if you have specific n items, you can use conditional state. you can also use Map instead of list , key will be name<String> and value will be codeIcon<int>